# How to define enums for key values in GraphQL

Tags: graphql, apollo-server

Ho do I define the enums keys in GraphQL schema?
The response that I'm expecting looks like below

```
 businessByState: { 
   MO: ["VALUE1", "VALUE2"],
   CA: ["VALUE1", "VALUE3", "VALUE4]
 }
```

I know I can define the enum for the values for the states but still wondering how I can define enum so that the key values will only be 2 letter state abbreviations?

Answer (score 2):

In GraphQL, each field of an Object type must be explicitly defined. For example:

```
type BusinessByState {
  AL: [String!]!
  AK: [String!]!
  AZ: [String!]!
  # and so on...
}
```

There is no syntax for defining multiple fields with the same type based on some input, like an existing enum.

If your typeDefs are just a string, you can use string templates to save yourself some typing, assuming you have some kind of array of state abbreviations:

```
const states = ['AL', 'AK', 'AZ', /** and so on **/]
const typeDefs = `
  enum STATES {
    ${states.join('\n')}
  }

  type BusinessByState {
    ${states.map(state => `${state}: [String!]!`).join('\n')}
  }
`
```